# How to interpret KDE distribution graph?

Tags: machine-learning, graphs, distribution, interpretation

I would like to know how to interpret this distribution graph. I have been doing an exercise from the book called 'Python for Finance Cookbook' by Eryk Lewinson. It does not give an in-depth explanation on this graph and i have watched videos on YouTube and it does not explain the comparison of distribution.

I would also like to know if this is positively skewed.

This is the distribution graph.
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: We need a little bit more context on where this graph comes from. On a first point of view it looks just to describe the Distribution of Age, so explaining you have a majority of 30-yo people on your data. There's no real interpretation, it helps you visualising how Age is distributed on your data...

Answer (score 2):

Please find beautiful,  explanation about [KDE](https://mathisonian.github.io/kde/),  In your graph on `X Coordinate`if the tail is stretching long towards right side then its positively skewed, it means most of your data points were distributed to left side and vise versa for negative skewness.

- Always we needs to ensure that data points on the graph needs to be equally distributed to form `Gaussian Normal Curve`for better outcome.
- There are various techniques to get rid of skewness , please find top 3 [methods](https://towardsdatascience.com/top-3-methods-for-handling-skewed-data-1334e0debf45) to play around with skewed data .

**Some prerequisites references for any Distribution Charts**

- [Percentiles, Quartiles, and Interquartile
  Range](http://my.ilstu.edu/%7Egjin/hsc204-hed/Module-5-Summary-Measure-2/Module-5-Summary-Measure-26.html)
- [Percentiles examples](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/percentiles-rank-range/)
- [Quartiles examples](https://www.statisticshowto.com/what-are-quartiles)